# How to pass C# parameter over window.showModalDialog() to MVC Action Result?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a page in my .Net MVC project that calls a pop up using javascript. Now I need to send a property that I get from my model over to the actionresult so that I can work with it.

What my page looks like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//function print() {
//    $(".btnPrint").printPage();

ShowPopUp = function () {
    window.showModalDialog("/FileUpload/GetPopupData/ --Pass my Model property, what to do? --", "wndPopUp", "width=300,height=500");
}
```

My Action Result where I want to use the property

```
public ActionResult GetPopupData(int consignmentId)
    {
        var test = consignmentId;
        //Call the pop up view and populate it accordingly
        return new GetDocumentTypeAction<ActionResult>
        {
            OnLoaded = m => View("../../Areas/Exports/Views/FileUpload/FileUpload", m),
            OnErrorOccured = (m) => Redirects.ToErrorPage()
        }.Execute(GtsClient);
    }
```

Comment: check this link and avoid using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728196/window-showmodaldialog-vs-window-open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a querystring:

```
"/FileUpload/GetPopupData?consignmentId=" + '@Model.ConsignmentId'
```

Just make sure that the property names match the method signature for the given action.

Comment: Or just ```/FileUpload/GetPopupData?consignmentId=@Model.ConsignmentId```